# Displaying hints

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe2

I have added hints to components on my form. When the components receive the focus, I'd like to set the caption of a label component to display the hint.

I have added a TApplicationEvents object and set the OnShowHint event to

```
procedure TImportFrm.ApplicationEvents1ShowHint(var HintStr: string;
  var CanShow: Boolean; var HintInfo: THintInfo);
begin
  HelpLbl.Caption := HintStr;
end;
```

However it seems that the ShowHint event only fires with mouse movements. Is there a way to fire the hint code when components receive focus, without having to implement the OnEnter event for every single component on the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a handler for `TScreen.OnActiveControlChange` in your main form's creation, and handle the hints in that event:

```
type
  TForm2=class(TForm)
  ...
  private
    procedure ScreenFocusControlChange(Sender: TObject);
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.OnActiveControlChange := ScreenFocusControlChange;
end;

procedure TForm2.ScreenFocusControlChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := ActiveControl.Hint;
  Label1.Update;
end;
```

Note that `Sender` won't do you much good; it's always `Screen`. You can filter (for instance, to only change the `Label.Caption` for edit controls) by testing the `ActiveControl`:

```
if (ActiveControl is TEdit) then
  // Update caption of label with ActiveControl.Hint
```

Note that if you'll need to reassign the event when you show child forms (to an event on that child form), or you'll always be updating the original form's label with the hints. The easiest way to do the reassignment is to give every form an `OnActiveControlChange` handler, and assign it in the form's `OnActivate` event and unassign it in the `OnDeactivate` event:

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.OnActiveControlChange := Self.ScreenActiveControlChange;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDeactivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.OnActiveControlChange := nil;
end;
```

This will allow you to update controls other than `Label1` on each form, and only use the hint changes on forms you want to do so.

Comment: Thanks Ken. That event is exactly what I was looking for, I just forgot to look outside the TForm object.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution is to use `OnIdle` event:

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Idle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
begin
  if Assigned(ActiveControl) then
    Label1.Caption:= ActiveControl.Hint;
end;
```

A more advanced solution is to override protected `ActiveChanged` method of `TForm`:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
  protected
    procedure ActiveChanged; override;
  end;

...

procedure TForm1.ActiveChanged;
begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(ActiveControl) then
    Label1.Caption:= ActiveControl.Hint;
end;
```

Receiving focus and `OnShowHint` are quite different events; `OnShowHint` can be triggered for non-focused control as well.

Comment: +1 For using OnIdle. A suggestion: use Screen.ActiveControl rather then (Self).ActiveControl to get it working application wide; not only for TForm1, but also for possible popup forms and suchlike.

Comment: This is the same method I use in my TKinect "Virtual Mouse Cursor" demo... works well! +1

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to implement the `OnEnter` event for every single component? You can create one generic method / event handler like:

```
procedure TForm1.AnyControlEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lbl1.Caption := TControl(Sender).Hint;
end;
```

and assign it to every component you placed on the form.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> it seems that the ShowHint event only fires with mouse movements

This is a normal behaviour. The problem you have ( it's a guess) is that hints are not fired directly. Don't try to make a workaround, what you try to do with MouseEnter is exactly what is already happening...the only difference is that you'be forget something...

Keep the event ApplicationEvents1ShowHint() as you've initially done but add this in the form constructor event:

```
Application.HintPause := 1;
```

And then hints will be displayed (almost) without delay.